# Appflow Deploy plugin causing error: 'uncaught (in promise) string resource id #0x0' in Ionic Capacitor project

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-appflow

Whenever I remove the "cordova-plugin-ionic": "5.4.7" from package.json, the error goes away and the platform.ready() fires correctly. I have tried removing then running the command 'ionic deploy add' according to the Appflow docs, but it just re-adds the plugin to the package.json.

I need to get rid of this error because it messes with the device ready event, causing the functions inside it to not run. My quick fix was to call the functions outside the platform.ready but it is not a true fix. Been searching for this for quite a while now.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this, other that removing the offending plugin? thx

Comment: Can you run `ionic info` and post the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your ios/android folders as well when you remove `cordova-plugin-ionic`. then add your platforms first, followed by `ionic deploy add`. This will put the configurations correctly.

If you are working on Capacitor v2, it will work.

Comment: Sorry it took so long, but this was the one that worked for me, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after I changed the name of the deploy channel in Ionic Dashboard. Removing the plugin, running ionic cap sync, and then re-adding the plugin with the correct channel name solved the problem.

Comment: I do not have access to our app Ionic Dashboard, but I will ask the person in-charge about the deploy channel name, I feel your answer can solve this, thanks.